# How to use MediaScannerConnection scanFile to scan a file in android

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-mediascanner

How to scan a file which has downloaded from web ? I have successfully downloaded the file from url and save it into Folder but When I open media player there are no media. After little bit search I just saw the posts that after downloading the file, It has to scan. so I have tried something like this

```
public class TagsPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    private CallbackContext callbackContext;
    private static Context context;
    private MediaScannerConnection conn;

    @Override
    public boolean execute(final String action, final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;

        final String songName = args.getString(0) + " " + myDomain;

        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {



            public void run() {
                    String resp;

                    final MediaScannerConnection conn;
        final String newFilePath = action;


                    String filePath = action;
                    AudioFile audioFile = null;
                    Tag audioTag = null;
                    AudioHeader audioHeader = null;

                    try{
                        TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);
                        AudioFile f = (MP3File) AudioFileIO.read(new File(filePath));
                        audioTag = f.getTag();

                        audioTag.setField(FieldKey.TITLE, songName);

                        f.commit();

                        resp = audioTag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE);

File file = new File(filePath);
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);
//MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { filePath }, null, null);



                    }catch (Exception e){
                        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                        resp = errors.toString();
                    }

                    PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, resp);
                    pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);

                }

        });


        return true;

    }
}
```

but it's showing the below errors

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Context.bindService(android.content.Intent, android.content.ServiceConnection, int)' on a null object reference
    at android.media.MediaScannerConnection.connect(MediaScannerConnection.java:119)
    at android.media.MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MediaScannerConnection.java:238)
    at TagsPlugin$1.run(TagsPlugin.java:91)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What am i doing wrong ? I just want to display the downloaded songs in media player in android.

Is there any phonegap/cordova plugin which do the same as i am doing ?

Answer (score 0):

I've done by myself using below code.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this.cordova.getActivity(),
                      new String[] { filePath }, null,
                      new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                  public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                      cbContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, uri.toString()));
                  }
            });
```